# Can I get the movies liked by my friends by using Facebook offline access?

Tags: facebook

I'm developing an application to display movies liked by my friends using Facebook API.Can I get the movies liked by my friends by using Facebook offline access

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. As the **[documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)** explains, the offline access

> enables your app to perform authorized
>   requests on behalf of the user at any
>   time. By default, most access tokens
>   expire after a short time period to
>   ensure applications only make requests
>   on behalf of the user when the are
>   actively using the application. This
>   permission makes the access token
>   returned by our OAuth endpoint
>   long-lived.

You will also need the **friends_likes** permission.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My question is: Can I get access to Friends Data using offline Access? or is there any limit to that

Comment: @mikerbrt you will also need the **friends_likes** permission.

Comment: If get access to Friends Likes Permission & offline access permission, I can get movies data in offline. Am I right?

Comment: The `offline_access` has been deprecated since 5th of July: http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/